# Redshift statement length exceeding while inserting data from a pandas dataframe to Redshift table

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I get this error

```
SyntaxError: Statement is too large. Statement Size: 19780406 bytes. Maximum Allowed: 16777216 bytes
```

I have even dropped some columns also to make the insertion possible but it doesn't work, can't drop even more columns.
I get this error for this code

```
red_conn = create_engine(
        f"postgresql:<credentials>)
from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(red_conn, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(
       conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany
        ):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True
df.to_sql('table1',red_conn,index=False,schema='schemaname',if_exists='append',\
      method='multi',chunksize=5000)
```

Using **Bulk copy** or **copy command** by storing this dataframe into CSV and then moving it to s3 and using copy command to insert is leading to ANSI errors and lot of type and data mismatches.
I prefer loading a dataframe directly to redshift be it batch wise or anything.
Please help how to insert the data into redshift from a dataframe without getting any statement length limitations.
Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift has a hard SQL statement length limit of 64K chars.

If you really want to do this you need to break up the insert values so that you don't hit this limit.  Since a single row can be larger that this (likely not) it is not possible to know exactly how many rows this is.  With some knowledge of max row size and safe numbers of rows (chunksize?) to push in one SQL statement this is doable (but not recommended).

Putting data into Redshift via SQL is generally a bad idea.  It works fine for a few ad hoc rows but it is very slow to execute at even modest levels of data.  SQL is code, not data, and is compiled by the cluster.  Pushing your data through the compiler is not the way to go.  (You'll make lots of friends when you tie up the compiler for a long time and they cannot get queries through.)

Saving your data to S3 is the way to go.  As you are finding out text formats have their limitations but if you have to go this route check out the CSV spec (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180).  If you can get your files into Parquet or ORC you will likely have less issues with text file interpretation.